# JsonSerializer cannot deserialize repeated field in protobuf message

Tags: json-deserialization

I declared protobuf message like this.

```css
message request {
    repeated sint32 Ids = 1;
}
```

and I tried to save this message in the form of json in DB.
Serialize worked well but when I deserialize it, 'Ids' field is empty.
What am I missing?

```css
var requrest = new Request;
foreach(Int16 Id in Ids) {
  request.Ids.Add(Id);
}

string SerializedReq = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request); // "{\"Ids\":[10,28]}"
var DeserializedReq = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Request>(SerializedReq); // {{}} empty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement a Converter and a ConverterFactory like this:

```
public class RepeatedFieldConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if (!typeToConvert.IsGenericType)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(RepeatedField<>))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(
        Type type,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        JsonConverter converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(RepeatedFieldConverter<>).MakeGenericType(
                new Type[] { itemType }),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { options },
            culture: null)!;

        return converter;
    }

    private class RepeatedFieldConverter<TItem> :
        JsonConverter<RepeatedField<TItem>>
    {
        private readonly JsonConverter<TItem> _valueConverter;
        private readonly Type _valueType;

        public RepeatedFieldConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            _valueConverter = (JsonConverter<TItem>)options
                .GetConverter(typeof(TItem));
            _valueType = typeof(TItem);
        }

        public override RepeatedField<TItem> Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }

            var repeatedField = new RepeatedField<TItem>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    return repeatedField;
                }

                TItem value = _valueConverter.Read(ref reader, _valueType, options)!;
                repeatedField.Add(value);
            }



            throw new JsonException();
        }



        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            RepeatedField<TItem> repatedField,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (TItem value in repatedField)
            {
                _valueConverter.Write(writer, value, options);
            }

            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var persons = new RepeatedField<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Joe"
});

//Converter for serializing is not mandatory, James Newton-King supports this out of the box ;-)

var jsonPersons = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(persons, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = { new RepeatedFieldConverterFactory() }
});

var deserializedPersons = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RepeatedField<Person>>(jsonPersons, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = { new RepeatedFieldConverterFactory() }
});
```

Comment: This code works for a RepeatedField<Person>, but it doesn't work if the RepeatedField is a property of Person class.  For example,  the person class contains a property Children and Children property is defined as RepeatedField<Child>.  This code will not deserialize the Children property correctly.   Unless I am missing something.

This has caused me endless hours of work, which led me back to just using Newtonsoft because it just works.

Comment: IIRC this class will ignore any types but RepeatedField<> it means if you have a parent class, Deserializer will use default/other converters until it visits the inner prop which is repeatedField. That's because of `CanConvert` method which returns false if you pass non RepeatedField<> type. @AaronP.Olds I'm not sure but you should take a look at your Default serializer to find the rootc

Comment: @Amir this does not work because C# protobuf generates read-only collections for repeatable, something like `Repeatable<T> Items { get; }` and it's been a long-time question about how to support read-only collections in System.Text, cf. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46372 . I'll post an answer (quite hacky and not very satisfying but that works) in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments above, the issue is with protobuf generating code with read-only collections. This is not supported yet for deserialization, cf. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46372.

Starting from .NET-7 there's a workaround with [custom contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts). My answer is totally adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76442118/4829094) and I just made it work with protobufs special collections:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata;
using Google.Protobuf.Collections;

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> CreateReadOnlyCollectionPropertySetters(Type type) => typeInfo =>
    {
        if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
            return;
        CreateReadOnlyCollectionPropertySetters(typeInfo);
    };

    public static void CreateReadOnlyCollectionPropertySetters(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        // Add synthetic collection setters.
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Get != null && property.Set == null && property.PropertyType.GetCollectionItemType() is { } itemType)
            {
                var method = typeof(JsonExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(JsonExtensions.CreateGetOnlyCollectionPropertySetter),
                                                              BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
                var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });
                var setter = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { property }) as Action<object, object?>;
                property.Set = setter;
            }
        }
    }

    static Action<object, object?>? CreateGetOnlyCollectionPropertySetter<TItem>(JsonPropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property.Get == null)
            return null;
        (var getter, var name) = (property.Get, property.Name);
        return (obj, value) =>
        {
            var oldValue = (ICollection<TItem>?)getter(obj);
            var newValue = value as ICollection<TItem>;
            if (newValue == oldValue)
                return;
            else if (oldValue == null || oldValue.IsReadOnly)
                throw new JsonException("Cannot populate list ${name} in ${obj}.");
            oldValue.Clear();
            if (newValue != null)
                foreach (var item in newValue)
                    oldValue.Add(item);
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType!;
        }
    }

    static readonly HashSet<Type> MutableCollectionBaseTypes = new[]
        {
            typeof(RepeatedField<>)
        }
        .ToHashSet();

    static Type? GetCollectionItemType(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsArray || type.IsPrimitive)
            return null;
        return type.BaseTypesAndSelf()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && MutableCollectionBaseTypes.Contains(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            .FirstOrDefault()?.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

In your case this can be used with:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
  Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.CreateReadOnlyCollectionPropertySetters(typeof(Requests)),  },
};
// content is the string serialization
var inst = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Requests>(content, options);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
using System;
using Google.Protobuf;
...
var message = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Request));
var result = (Request)JsonParser.Default.Parse(json, message?.Descriptor);
```

I stole it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76013514/829755

Comment: Indeed Google.Protobuf has its own parser but it lacks mandatory functionalities to be used in real-life applications. For instance, there's no custom parser that can be injected.