# How to deserialize json to protobuf that contains collections?

Tags: c#, json, grpc

I have a json file that I would like to deserialize to a C# protobuf object. I'm able to deserialize the json, however any repeated fields are not preserved and are instead null, I believe this is related to how the protobuf objects are represented in c# with readonly fields.

```
{
  "Name": "Anna",
  "PlacesTravelled": [
    {
      "Country": "Spain",
      "City": "Barcelona"
    },
    {
      "Country": "England",
      "City": "London"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
message Person {
    string name = 1;
    repeated Location PlacesTravelled = 2;
}

message Location {
    string Country = 1;
    string City = 2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the c# classes (as text, not as a screen shot, for reasons explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this solution:

```
using System;
using Google.Protobuf;
...
var message = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YOUR_CLASS));
var result = (YOUR_CLASS)JsonParser.Default.Parse(json, message?.Descriptor);
```

Comment: Apart from `using Google.Protobuf;`, where is ProtoBuf involved here?

Comment: I wondered if protobuf had its own json parser, thanks

Comment: wonderful! some minor problems I had to solve were a) YOUR_CLASS can't be an array, so I had to split my json input into array elements and b) I had to translate property names from CamelCase to snake_case.