# How can we deserialize to ProtoBuf from huge json using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable with different property name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, protocol-buffers, system.text.json

I have huge json file so I used below code and actually it works.

```
using (FileStream? fileStream = new FileStream("hugefile.json", FileMode.Open))
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<Person?> people = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Person?>(fileStream);
    await foreach (Person? person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, my name is {person.Name}!");
    }
}
```

My problem is in the Person class which is generated with protobuf. It contains a property which name is TrackingDatas and it has ProtoMember attribute you can see below. But in my huge json the property name is TrackingData. I want to deserialize it but without any add or delete from ProtoBuf class. Does anyone have any idea?

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, Name = @"TrackingData")]
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<EntityTrackingActivity> TrackingDatas { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<EntityTrackingActivity>();
```

I tried this code below to change name of property but it did not work for me.

```
public class CustomNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> NameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        [nameof(OASISLevel2TrackingPacket.EntityTracking.TrackingDatas)] = "TrackingData"
    };

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        var a = NameMapping.GetValueOrDefault(name, name);

        return a;
    }
}
```

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
                    {
                        PropertyNamingPolicy = new CustomNamingPolicy()
                    };
```

```
using (FileStream? fileStream = new FileStream("hugefile.json", FileMode.Open))
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<Person?> people = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Person?>(fileStream, options);
    await foreach (Person? person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, my name is {person.Name}!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a JSON sample (Just one or two array entries would be sufficient) + the `Person ` and `EntityTrackingActivity` classs -- i.e., a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you modify your `Person` type at all?  For instance could you add a constructor, or add attributes?

Comment: Also, are you using .NET 7, .NET 6, or something earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. The name of the property `TrackingDatas` does not match the JSON name `"TrackingData"`, but your type is auto-generated by Protobuf so you cannot easily modify it.

   You have correctly fixed this by adding a `PropertyNamingPolicy` that remaps all properties named `TrackingDatas` (in all types) to `"TrackingData"`.
2. Your collection property

   ```
   public List<EntityTrackingActivity> TrackingDatas { get; } = new ();
   ```

   is **read only**, but System.Text.Json **does not support deserializing read-only collection properties prior to .NET 8**.

   For confirmation, see *[Can System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer serialize collections on a read-only property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59748093)* and *[What's new in .NET 8: Read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#read-only-properties)*.

So, what are your options for resolving the second problem?

**Firstly**, you could deserialize to some appropriate `PersonDTO` then map the DTO to `Person` using, say, AutoMapper.

**Secondly** in .NET 5 and later, if your automatically generated `Person` class was declared as `partial`, e.g.:

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public partial class EntityTracking
{
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, Name = @"TrackingData")]
    public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<EntityTrackingActivity> TrackingDatas { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<EntityTrackingActivity>();      
}

[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public partial class Person : EntityTracking
{
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"Name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public partial class EntityTrackingActivity
{
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You could add a parameterized constructor with an `List<EntityTrackingActivity> trackingDatas` argument and mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute) like so:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person() { } // Add parameterless constructor if not already auto-generated by protobuf
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Person(List<EntityTrackingActivity> trackingDatas) => this.TrackingDatas.AddRange(trackingDatas ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(trackingDatas)));
}
```

And now you will be able to deserialize the `TrackingDatas` property.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YBKKm2).

**Thirdly**, in .NET 7 and later, Microsoft has added the ability to programmatically customize the [serialization contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) that System.Text.Json creates for each .NET type.  Using this API you can add a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to map all JSON property names to the value of `ProtoMemberAttribute.Name`, and to add synthetic setters to get-only `List<T>` properties.  This approach completely avoids the need to modify your types in any way.

First, add the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> InitializeProtoMemberNames(Type type) => typeInfo => 
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
            return;
        // Fix property name(s).
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            // Set the JSON property name to be the same as ProtoMemberAttribute.Name
            var name = property.AttributeProvider?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute), true)
                .OfType<global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault()
                ?.Name;
            if (name != null)
                property.Name = name;
        }
    };

    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> InitializeGetOnlyListSetters(Type type) => typeInfo => 
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
            return;
        // Add synthetic list setters.
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Get != null && property.Set == null && property.PropertyType.GetListItemType() is {} itemType)
            {
                var method = typeof(JsonExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(JsonExtensions.CreateGetOnlyListPropertySetter),
                                                              BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
                var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { itemType });
                var setter = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { property }) as Action<object, object?>;
                property.Set = setter;
            }
        }
    };
    
    static Action<Object,Object?>? CreateGetOnlyListPropertySetter<TItem>(JsonPropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property.Get == null)
            return null;
        (var getter, var name) = (property.Get, property.Name);
        return (obj, value) =>
        {
            var oldValue = (List<TItem>?)getter(obj);
            var newValue = value as List<TItem>;
            if (newValue == oldValue)
                return;
            else if (oldValue == null)
                throw new JsonException("Cannot populate list ${name} in ${obj}.");
            oldValue.Clear();
            if (newValue != null)
                oldValue.AddRange(newValue);
        };
    }

    static MemberInfo? GetMemberInfo(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo);
    
    static Type? GetListItemType(this Type type) =>
        type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) ? type.GetGenericArguments()[0] : null;
}
```

And then deserialize e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { 
            JsonExtensions.InitializeProtoMemberNames(typeof(Person)), 
            JsonExtensions.InitializeGetOnlyListSetters(typeof(Person)) 
        },
    },
};

await using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<Person?> people = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Person?>(fileStream, options);
    await foreach (Person? person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, my name is \"{person?.Name}\", my tracking data is {JsonSerializer.Serialize(person?.TrackingDatas.Select(t => t.Id))}!");
    }           
}
```

Notes:

- As explained in *[Asynchronous streams and disposables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await#asynchronous-streams-and-disposables)*, the `await using` syntax should be used to dispose of file streams when writing async code.
- In order to actually enable asynchronous `FileStream` access, pass `useAsync : true` to the `FileStream` constructor. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-filestream-ctor(system-string-system-io-filemode-system-io-fileaccess-system-io-fileshare-system-int32-system-boolean)) for a discussion of the possible performance implications.
- `CustomNamingPolicy` is no longer needed with this approach.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27yvUc).

**Finally**, in .NET 8 and later, populating of preallocated read-only collection properties is supported out of the box by setting

```
JsonSerializerOptions.PreferredObjectCreationHandling = 
    JsonObjectCreationHandling.Populate;
```

Thus `InitializeGetOnlyListSetters()` is no longer needed and your code can be simplified e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PreferredObjectCreationHandling = JsonObjectCreationHandling.Populate,           
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.InitializeProtoMemberNames(typeof(Person))),
};

await using var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
var people = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Person?>(fileStream, options);
await foreach (var person in people)
{
    // Code to process each person
}
```

For details, see *[Populate initialized properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/populate-properties)*.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z4GRku).

Comment: Thank you so much we find a solution thanks to you!